# How to send a part HTML with twig expression via controller as a variable inside $this->render()?

Tags: twig, twig-extension

I want to send a part of HTML as a variable inside the array params in $this->render() function.

I use this variable in my view, {{ other_product | raw }} but it doesn't format the TWIG syntax as well and get the correct path.

```
 public function productsAction(){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $produits =    $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Products')->findBy(array('disponibility' => 1));

    $other_product='<a href="{{ path(similar_product) }}" target="_blank">Other product</a>';

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:products/layout/products.html.twig', array(
        'products' => $products,
        'other_product' => $other_product)
    );
}
```

This is the result 
`<a href="{{ path(similar_product) }}" target="_blank">Other product</a>` How to format or filter this variable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Patternlab / Twig Variable Interpolation doesn't work with string from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955886/patternlab-twig-variable-interpolation-doesnt-work-with-string-from-json)

Comment: Thank you @DarkBee for your answer but I have  a new idea after seeing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081910/what-to-use-instead-of-twig-loader-string

Comment: Should be a better solution seeing that `Twig_Loader_String` is deprecated now

Comment: $templates = array('part_html_twig' => '<a href="{{ route_name }}"  target="_blank">{{ text_link }}</a>');
        $env = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_Array($templates));

Comment: I do that in the `render()` function `return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:products/layout/products.html.twig', array(
            'products' => $products,
            'part_html' => $env->render('part_html_twig', array(
                                                            'route_name' => 'similar_product',
                                                            'text_link' => 'Other product'
                                                        )
                                                    ))
        );` then `{{ part_html |raw }} ` to the view and it's work !!!

Comment: Make it an answer and self-accept it then :)